# Making Picker compatible with other BinaryInteger types

Tags: swift, swiftui, picker

`Picker` only works properly when used with `Int`, when using any other type of `BinaryInteger` it doesn't update the selection at all. To remedy this, I want to make a `CompatilibityPicker` but I must admit my understanding of how `Binding`s actually work is causing me a lot of trouble. Here is my current code :

```swift
struct CompatibilityPicker<Label, SelectionValue, Content> : View where Label : View, SelectionValue : BinaryInteger, Content : View {

    var content : () -> Content
    var label : Label

    @Binding var _selection : SelectionValue

    var selection : Int {
        get {
            Int(_selection)
        }
        set {
            self._selection = SelectionValue(newValue)
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        // This line shows errors about selection and I don't know how to fix them,
        // using $selection does not work either.
        Picker(label, selection: selection, content: content)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is fixed variant - separated external binding and internal proxy binding to make transform

```
struct CompatibilityPicker<Label, SelectionValue, Content>: View where Label : View, SelectionValue : BinaryInteger, Content : View {

    var content : () -> Content
    var label : Label

    @Binding var selection : SelectionValue

    private var value: Binding<Int> { Binding<Int>(
        get: {
            Int(selection)
        },
        set: {
            self.selection = SelectionValue($0)
        })
    }

    var body: some View {
        Picker(selection: value, content: content) { label }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh interesting ! I hadn't thought of making the type of the computed property `Binding<Int>`. Great idea !

Comment: (by the way neither your code nor my original conforms to `View` which it should, I kinda forgot to add that part)