# Type '()' cannot conform to View (except it definitely is a View, no shenanigans this time)

Tags: swift, swiftui, view, picker

I know it's a weird title but there are lots of posts with similar titles and completely different problems. Mostly people writing other stuff than `View` code inside their view, which I am not doing (as far as I can tell).

I'm trying to make `Picker` compatible with other `BinaryInteger` types since it doesn't work with anything but `Int`, and I'm having some trouble getting the Previews to work. Here's the code :

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct CompatibilityPicker<Label, SelectionValue, Content> : View where Label : StringProtocol, SelectionValue : BinaryInteger, Content : View {
    
    var content : () -> Content
    var label : Label
    
    @Binding private var _selection : SelectionValue
    
    private var selection: Binding<Int> { Binding<Int>(
        get: {
            Int(_selection)
        },
        set: {
            self._selection = SelectionValue($0)
        })
    }
    
    init(_ label : Label, selection : SelectionValue, content : @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.label = label
        self._selection = selection
        self.content = content
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Picker(label, selection: selection, content: content)
    }
}

struct CompatibilityPicker_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    @State static var selection : UInt8 = 4
    
    static var previews: some View {
        CompatibilityPicker("Difficulty", selection: selection) { //error : Type'()' cannot conform to 'View'
            Text("Easy").tag(0)
            Text("Normal").tag(1)
            Text("Hard").tag(2)
        }
    }
}
```

What gives ? I have a normal `Picker` that uses the exact same syntax and that works, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

---

Thanks to @RobMayoff's solution, I am one step further ahead, however seemingly nonsensical errors have shown up that don't clear with cmd+shift+k :

```swift
init(_ label : Label, selection : SelectionValue, @ViewBuilder content : @escaping () -> Content) {
    self.content = content
    self.label = label
    self._selection = selection //variable self._selection used before initialised
    // This stays on this line if I change the order,
} // Return from initializer without initialising all stored properties
// That is not true, as far as I can tell
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shenaniganically, you are trying to use `ViewBuilder` syntax in the trailing closure, but you didn't adorn `content` with the `@ViewBuilder` annotation. So Swift infers that the trailing closure returns `()` (also called `Void`).

Change the `init` declaration to mention `@ViewBuilder`:

```
struct CompatibilityPicker<blah blah blah>: View where blah blah blah {

    init(
        _ label : Label,
        selection : SelectionValue,
        @ViewBuilder content : @escaping () -> Content
     // ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ) {
        blah blah blah
```

### UPDATE

```
    @Binding private var _selection : SelectionValue

    blah blah blah

    init(_ label : Label, selection : SelectionValue, content : @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.label = label
        self._selection = selection
        self.content = content
    }
```

The `_selection` variable is wrapped by the `Binding` wrapper, which means that it is really a computed property. The stored property is named `__selection` (note the two underscores) and has type `Binding<SelectionValue>`. Because `_selection` is a computed property, `init` cannot mention it until all stored properties are initialized. Probably you should change `init` to take a `Binding<SelectionValue>` argument instead of a `SelectionValue` argument:

```
    init(
        _ label : Label,
        selection : Binding<SelectionValue>,
        @ViewBuilder content : @escaping () -> Content
     // ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ) {
        self.label = label
        self.content = content
        __selection = selection
    }
```

### UPDATE 2

I looked at [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73253708/making-picker-compatible-with-other-binaryinteger-types) and your code here and I think I know what you mean by “it doesn't work with anything but `Int`”.

The problem as that, when you say `Text("Easy").tag(0)`, Swift treats `0` as an `Int`. If your `Picker`'s `SelectionValue` is, say, `Int16`, then indeed the `Picker` will not be able to use the `0` tag because the types don't match.

You can make your `tag` work with `Picker` by giving `0` the correct type. For example: `Text("Easy").tag(0 as Int16)`.

However, my recommendation is that you stop mucking about with `CompatibilityPicker`. It is a symptom of [primitive obsession](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=primitive+obsession&t=osx&ia=web). The idiomatic solution is to use an `enum` for your tags:

```
enum Difficulty: Hashable {
    case easy
    case medium
    case hard
}

struct Demo1: View {
    @State var difficulty: Difficulty = .easy

    var body: some View {
        Picker("Difficulty", selection: $difficulty) {
            Text("Easy").tag(Difficulty.easy)
            Text("Medium").tag(Difficulty.medium)
            Text("Hard").tag(Difficulty.hard)
        }
    }
}
```

You could go even further and do this:

```
extension Difficulty: CaseIterable { }

extension Difficulty {
    var stringKey: LocalizedStringKey {
        switch self {
        case .easy: return "Easy"
        case .medium: return "Medium"
        case .hard: return "Hard"
        }
    }
}

struct Demo2: View {
    @State var difficulty: Difficulty = .easy

    var body: some View {
        Picker("Difficulty", selection: $difficulty) {
            ForEach(Difficulty.allCases, id: \.self) {
                Text($0.stringKey).tag($0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay so that *works* but it has made nonsensical errors appear everywhere and they don't go away when I clean the build thingy

More specifically : Whichever property I initialise last in `init` is said to be "used before being initialised" and the init says it's "returning before all properties are initialised" despite the fact it is false.

Comment: I cannot help you with your new errors if you don't tell me what they are.

Comment: comment edited to tell you what they are, going to edit main post

Comment: I do understand your point about primitive obsession, sadly I'm interfacing with Minecraft's code which uses an Int8 to represent difficulty. I would have definitely chosen an enum if I were to choose myself, I think I'm going to try and turn it into an enum at the decoding step actually.

Comment: I've gone ahead and accepted your answer, I think the suggestion to replace difficulty with an enum made me realise this is an XY problem. I'm just going to use an enum with a RawValue type of Int8, and that'll take care of the encoding/decoding

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working variant based on my previous answer. Tested with Xcode 14 / iOS 16

There are several errors in code in question: selection value w/o binding, content w/o view builder, conflict of hidden binding autogenerated properties, etc., so I just updated a bit my previous solution.

[image: demo]

```
struct CompatibilityPicker<Label, SelectionValue, Content>: View where Label : StringProtocol, SelectionValue : BinaryInteger, Content : View {

    var label : Label
    @Binding var selection : SelectionValue
    var content : () -> Content

    init(_ label : Label, selection : Binding<SelectionValue>, @ViewBuilder content : @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.label = label
        self._selection = selection
        self.content = content
    }

    private var value: Binding<Int> { Binding<Int>(
        get: {
            Int(selection)
        },
        set: {
            self.selection = SelectionValue($0)
        })
    }

    var body: some View {
        Picker(label, selection: value, content: content)
    }
}

struct CompatibilityPicker_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    struct TestView: View {
        @State var selection : UInt8 = 1
        var body: some View {
            CompatibilityPicker("Difficulty", selection: $selection) {
                Text("Easy").tag(0)
                Text("Normal").tag(1)
                Text("Hard").tag(2)
            }
        }
    }
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's different from what I was doing, but evidently it does work. Thank you for your help ! Let's hope they end up fixing `Picker`, I have reported the bug but no news so far